# How to take power

Tags: pascal, freepascal, exponent

```
K = (S * (P/100/12)) / (1 - (1 + (P/100/12))^(-Y*12))
```

where `S`, `P`, and `Y` are input.

How to get the `K` value in Free Pascal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use the ** operator

This one isn't implemented/overloaded by default, but unit math does it for integer and float

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`power`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/power.html) or [`intpower`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/intpower.html) function.